# How to not store password in .pypirc?

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to set up a private Pypi cloud using CloudPypi. And I really don't want store my password in .pypirc. I want to be prompt to type in my password every time I upload a package.

In [Python document about .pypirc](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/packageindex.html#the-pypirc-file), it says:

> password, that will be used to authenticate. If omitted the user will
>   be prompt to type it when needed.

But how do you "omit" the password here? I tried leaving the password line blank, tried do "password : " or "password : password". None of these works.

Comment: Same question here, it looks like Python didn't check for NoneType password, `python setup.py sdist upload` complains `TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly`

Comment: It's an old issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue18454

Answer (score 3):

You omit the entire line completely:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
repository: <repository-url>
username: <username>
```

This has been tested on Python 3.6.2 and pip 9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Omitting `password:` in `.pypirc` is broken since `setuptools 42.0.2` (Dec 2019), and will not be fixed (see https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2006 ).

Instead, you should use `twine` to upload packages. It will prompt for the password if omitted from `.pypirc` . See https://twine.readthedocs.io

Example:

```sh
pip install twine
twine upload -r mypypi dist/* --verbose
```